# convert webp to jpg error: "no decode delegate for this image format" and "missing an image filename"

Tags: imagemagick, images, image-manipulation

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.
I've installed `libwebp2` & `libwebp-dev`

So far, no example found on the net of converting webp to jpg.

Some webp files can easily converted by using imagemagick with command

```
convert file.webp file.jpg
```

but lots of webp files cannot be converted and give error:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `file.webp' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: missing an image filename `file.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

--------added

This is the file: http://www.filedropper.com/file_144

Comment: Could you post some of the files that cannot be converted so we can have a go?

Comment: Any errors when ImageMagick fails to convert?

Comment: @dartonw Error has been updated

Comment: @terdon I have no idea any image hosting support webp

Comment: Strange that IM would convert some webp files and not others. Can the ones that fail be viewed in a browser or image editor (perhaps they are corrupt)? How did you install IM? AFAIK, it needs to be specifically compiled with webp support after installing libwebp[-devel].

Comment: Just upload the file to Dropbox or something similar. Since I don't have any .webp files, I have no way of testing.

Comment: @terdon, you can find some samples at https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery1.

Comment: Does `convert -list format` contain WebP?

Comment: `convert -list format` dont have WebP

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Google already provided the tool to decode webp images in the `libwebp` package, your uploaded file works on Arch.

```
dwebp file.webp -o abc.png
```

For the encoding tool, check the `cwebp` command.

In Ubuntu you can install the tools with:

```
sudo apt install webp
```

On RHEL/CentOS:

```
 yum install libwebp libwebp-tools
```

And you might consider [using this online tool](http://www.zamzar.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately dwebp only converts webp to png, but not to jpg.

Comment: @rumpel thx, it failed to open the .jpg, but when I put .png it worked!

Comment: In 14.04 I needed to install the package `webp` it was not available until I installed that. I was confused because I had install all the `libwebp` and `libweb-dev` packages.

Comment: works on fedora/EL, just install libwebp-tools

Comment: Use `dwebp` for webp->png, and then `convert` for png->jpg.  Using pipe.  `dwebp 1.webp -o - | convert - 1.jpg`

Comment: For windows use the following command
for %f in (*.webp) do dwebp.exe  "%f" -o "%~nf.png"

Comment: In 2018, dwebp converted to jpg for me. Thanks!

Comment: On CentOS `dwebp` command was only available after: `yum install libwebp.x86_64` AND `yum install libwebp-tools.x86_64`

Comment: The dwebp doc says nothing about JPG as target format: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/dwebp

Comment: @steve Just the command I was looking for, can you please convert your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70622/convert-webp-to-jpg-error-no-decode-delegate-for-this-image-format-and-missi#comment519949_70673) to an answer ?

Comment: @SebMa - sure, done

Answer (score 54):

ffmpeg can do this. Useful if you already have ffmpeg. No need for installing other tools.

Simply:

```
ffmpeg -i file.webp out.png
```

Comment: It works, but the png is 11x larger.

Comment: it works. It is good for `jpg` image, but `png` format is `very large`.

Comment: This worked for me, using dwebp produced broken jpegs on the images I did.

Answer (score 28):

Convert all webp files within a directory

```
find ./ -name "*.webp" -exec dwebp {} -o {}.png \;
```

Note: dwebp is in the libwebp package

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 I needed to install it with `sudo apt-get install webp`.

Comment: Dont know if ment as a feature or a bug, but all the files will be saved as `file.webpg.png` instead of simply `file.png`

Comment: It's a feature for simplicity... I have a image hashing algorithm which automatically renames images, so I intended to rename the files using that.

Comment: Using ffmpeg: `find ./ -name "*.webp" -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.jpeg \;`

Answer (score 11):

From the directory containing the `webp` files:

```
for x in *.webp; do ffmpeg -i "$x" "${x%.webp}.jpg"; done
```

Comment: Add `-loglevel quiet` as ffmpeg option to suppress the copious log output.

Comment: This brought the image quality significantly down.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dwebp` for webp->png, and then `convert` for png->jpg. Using pipe.

```
dwebp 1.webp -o - | convert - 1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another online tool available here which can help you on this:

- http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

but if you want a local tool, you can use this one:

- https://code.google.com/p/webp/downloads/detail?name=webpconv&can=2&q=

and use it like this:

1) `chmod a+x webpconv`

2) `./webpconv -format PNG <YOUR_WEBP_FILE>.webp`

The overall structure is like this:

`webpconv [-output_dir dir] [-format format] [-quality quality] input_file(s)`

**Example)** To convert a .png image to WebP with a quality of 90 you would enter:

`webpconv -quality 90 /home/user/image_name.png`

and to convert a WebP file to a PNG one:

`webpconv -format PNG /home/user/image_name.webp`

Answer (score 0):

To convert multiple jpg to webp, using [cwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp):

`find ./ -name "*.jpg" -exec cwebp -q 70 {} -o {}.webp \`

Thunar Custom Action:

`for file in %F; do cwebp "$file" -o "${file%%.*}".webp; done`

Thunar Custom Action, moving webp images to subfolder:

`mkdir %d/webp && cd %d; for file in %N; do cwebp "$file" -o "webp/${file%%.*}".webp; done`

Cwebp's default quality setting is 75.

Answer (score 0):

install the *webp* package with `sudo apt install webp`, after that it should work.

Comment: why the downvote? this exact solution got incorporated into the accepted answer _after_ I gave mine

Answer (score 0):

`for x in ls *.webp; do  ffmpeg -i $x ${x%.webp}.jpg; done` which is [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372587/24453) stolen from [Byram Sewell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237162/byram-sewell) and [Jeff Bowman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426891/jeff-bowman) https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844019/146745

Answer (score -1):

I found this method faster for my 1 time need.

1. Take screenshot with webp image open in chrome.
2. Paste into paint program.
3. Crop and save.

Comment: The questioner was looking for a command line solution...

Comment: I think it could be made as a command line by using Shutter and taking a screenshot of a window without window decorations, all in a script; could be fun to code :)

Comment: Screenshots loose much of the original quality, therefore, they voted "-1" to your answer. It is not a good solution.